# OSGi, JPA Eclipselink, Postgresql : Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.eclipse.persistence.jpa.PersistenceProvider cannot be found

Tags: java, jpa, osgi, eclipselink, postgresql-9.1

I create two rcp-bundle. First bundle implements JPA - service, second - client.
Use next technlogies:

OSGi, JPA Eclipselink, RCP Eclipse, RAP Eclipse, Eclipse Equinox

## **Service bundle:**

```
public class JpaUtil {

    private static EntityManagerFactory emf;
    private static Map<String, Object> properties = new HashMap<String, Object>();

public EntityManagerFactory getEntityManagerFactory() {

        try {
            properties.put(PersistenceUnitProperties.JDBC_DRIVER, "org.postgresql.Driver");
            properties.put(PersistenceUnitProperties.JDBC_URL, "jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/db");
            properties.put(PersistenceUnitProperties.JDBC_USER, "db");
            properties.put(PersistenceUnitProperties.JDBC_PASSWORD, "db");
            properties.put(PersistenceUnitProperties.CLASSLOADER, this.getClass().getClassLoader());

            emf = new PersistenceProvider().createEntityManagerFactory("service", properties);
        } catch (Throwable e) {
            System.err.println("Error create initializer SessionFactory " + e);
            e.printStackTrace();
            throw new ExceptionInInitializerError(e);
        }

        return emf;
    }

}
```

**DAO implemenation:**

```
public class HotelJPAImpl implements HotelJPA {     

    @Override
    public boolean checkStatusRoom(Integer numbRoom) {

    EntityManager em = new JpaUtil().getEntityManagerFactory().createEntityManager();               

        boolean status;
        try{        
            Long l = Long.valueOf(numbRoom.longValue());
            Hotel hotel = (Hotel) em.find(Hotel.class, numbRoom);
            status = hotel.getIsStatus();           
        }finally{
            em.close();         
        }           
        return status;
    }

}
```

**ServiceActivator:**

```
public class ServiceActivator implements BundleActivator {
    ServiceRegistration<HotelJPA> ServiceRegistration;

    @Override
    public void start(BundleContext context) throws Exception {


        HotelJPA hotelJPA = new HotelJPAImpl();
        ServiceRegistration = (ServiceRegistration<HotelJPA>) context
                .registerService(HotelJPA.class.getName(), hotelJPA,
                        null);
    }

    @Override
    public void stop(BundleContext context) throws Exception {
        ServiceRegistration.unregister();
    }
}
```

**persistence.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence version="2.1"
    xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_1.xsd">
    <persistence-unit name="service">

        <class>service.table.Hotel</class>
        <properties>        
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.url" value="jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/db" />
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.user" value="db" />
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.password" value="db" />
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.driver" value="org.postgresql.Driver" />
        </properties>
    </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

## **Client bundle:**

**Activator:**

```
public class Activator implements BundleActivator {

    ServiceReference<HotelJPA> serviceReference;    

    @Override
    public void start(BundleContext context) throws Exception {

        serviceReference = (ServiceReference<HotelJPA>)context.getServiceReference(HotelJPA.class.getName());       
        HotelJPA hotelJPA = (HotelJPA) context.getService(serviceReference);

        System.out.println(hotelJPA.checkStatusRoom(1));

    }

    @Override
    public void stop(BundleContext context) throws Exception {

        context.ungetService(serviceReference);

    }

}
```

## **When I start bundle is such an exception:**

```
!SESSION 2013-10-05 19:21:27.348 -----------------------------------------------
eclipse.buildId=unknown
java.version=1.7.0_25
java.vendor=Oracle Corporation
BootLoader constants: OS=win32, ARCH=x86_64, WS=win32, NL=en_US
Command-line arguments:  -dev file:C:/My_documents/Java/eclipse/workspace/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.pde.core/RAP/dev.properties -os win32 -ws win32 -arch x86_64 -consoleLog -console -data C:\My_documents\Java\eclipse\workspace/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.rap.tools.launch/RAP

!ENTRY com.client 4 0 2013-10-05 19:21:27.898
!MESSAGE FrameworkEvent ERROR
!STACK 0
org.osgi.framework.BundleException: Exception in hotel.client.Activator.start() of bundle com.client.
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleContextImpl.startActivator(BundleContextImpl.java:734)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleContextImpl.start(BundleContextImpl.java:683)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleHost.startWorker(BundleHost.java:381)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.AbstractBundle.resume(AbstractBundle.java:390)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.Framework.resumeBundle(Framework.java:1176)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.StartLevelManager.resumeBundles(StartLevelManager.java:559)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.StartLevelManager.resumeBundles(StartLevelManager.java:544)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.StartLevelManager.incFWSL(StartLevelManager.java:457)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.StartLevelManager.doSetStartLevel(StartLevelManager.java:243)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.StartLevelManager.dispatchEvent(StartLevelManager.java:438)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.StartLevelManager.dispatchEvent(StartLevelManager.java:1)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.EventManager.dispatchEvent(EventManager.java:230)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.EventManager$EventThread.run(EventManager.java:340)
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/eclipse/persistence/jpa/PersistenceProvider
    at hotel.service.daoimpl.HotelJPAImpl.checkStatusRoom(HotelJPAImpl.java:70)
    at hotel.client.Activator.start(Activator.java:21)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleContextImpl$1.run(BundleContextImpl.java:711)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleContextImpl.startActivator(BundleContextImpl.java:702)
    ... 12 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.eclipse.persistence.jpa.PersistenceProvider cannot be found by com.service_1.0.0.qualifier
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClassInternal(BundleLoader.java:501)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:421)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:412)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.baseadaptor.DefaultClassLoader.loadClass(DefaultClassLoader.java:107)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    ... 17 more
Root exception:
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/eclipse/persistence/jpa/PersistenceProvider
    at hotel.service.daoimpl.HotelJPAImpl.checkStatusRoom(HotelJPAImpl.java:70)
    at hotel.client.Activator.start(Activator.java:21)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleContextImpl$1.run(BundleContextImpl.java:711)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleContextImpl.startActivator(BundleContextImpl.java:702)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleContextImpl.start(BundleContextImpl.java:683)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleHost.startWorker(BundleHost.java:381)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.AbstractBundle.resume(AbstractBundle.java:390)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.Framework.resumeBundle(Framework.java:1176)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.StartLevelManager.resumeBundles(StartLevelManager.java:559)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.StartLevelManager.resumeBundles(StartLevelManager.java:544)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.StartLevelManager.incFWSL(StartLevelManager.java:457)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.StartLevelManager.doSetStartLevel(StartLevelManager.java:243)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.StartLevelManager.dispatchEvent(StartLevelManager.java:438)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.StartLevelManager.dispatchEvent(StartLevelManager.java:1)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.EventManager.dispatchEvent(EventManager.java:230)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.EventManager$EventThread.run(EventManager.java:340)
```

**Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.eclipse.persistence.jpa.PersistenceProvider cannot be found by com.service_1.0.0.qualifier**

```
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClassInternal(BundleLoader.java:501)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:421)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:412)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.baseadaptor.DefaultClassLoader.loadClass(DefaultClassLoader.java:107)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    ... 17 more

!ENTRY org.eclipse.osgi 4 0 2013-10-05 19:21:27.901
!MESSAGE Bundle com.client_1.0.0.qualifier [52] is not active.
```

## **Help, please! Thanks.**

Comment: You reinitialize your "emf" variable each time the getEntityManagerFactory() function is called. You also use @PersistenceUnit annotation, although you initialize that variable programmatically. It would be nice to fix the sample code as it is not clear in this way if there is any runtime code manipulation on the class due to the annotation.

Comment: Thank you. Already corrected

Answer (score 0):

The exception says that the classloader of the bundle "service" does not see the PersistenceProvider class of EclipseLink.

Probably the package org.eclipse.persistence.jpa is not imported in the service bundle (Import-Package).

Comment: Thanks for the advice. But the decision was to put the library in the classpath.